# calculating average based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I am trying to put together a formula that gives me the average total for an order if the order contains a specific item in it, how can I compute that?

For example if the table looks like

```
Order# | Item | Total for Entire order
a        Apple       50
a        Juice       50
a        Chicken     50
a        Bread       50
b        Bread       23
b        fish        23
c        Chicken     43
c        Wine        43
c        rice        43
```

I want get the avg total of all orders that contain Chicken in them at least once? but dont want to count the total of once order twice in my average calculation - Thanks for looking

Comment: Look into [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690)

Comment: Can `Chicken` be in the same `Order#` more than once?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes it can!

Answer (score 1):

If one has the new Dynamic Array formulas:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:C10,B2:B10="Chicken")),,3))
```

If not:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B10="Chicken")*(C2:C10))/(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,"Chicken")+(B2:B10<>"Chicken")))/SUMPRODUCT((B2:B10="Chicken")/(COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,B2:B10,"Chicken")+(B2:B10<>"Chicken")))
```

[image]

Comment: I like your answers. I would not have thought to do it that way. I'm curious, and maybe I misread the question, but if I put the values in excel and manually average with =AVERAGE(C2,C3,C4,C5,C8,C9,C10) I get 47 same as my UDF. Why do your formulas return 46.5? I'm not saying your wrong I'm right. I just feel like I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: Also I was unaware of dynamic array formulas. Very cool. I'll be using those in the future. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using VBA this function will do what you want.

`=Average_Orders_Subset(range, criteria)`

I changed this from my original answer to improve the functionality and added comments so you can see what it's doing. With the function you can add as many orders as you like. I have also tested it and it will work if the order letters are changed to numbers i.e. a = 1, b= 2 ect... Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to ask if you have any questions.

If your data starts in cell A1 it works like this:
Example: `=Average_Orders_Subset(A1:C13,"Chicken")`

[image]

With this version you can average for Chicken, rice, bread, anything you want.
In case you don't know [here's](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) how to add the code to the workbook. 
If you want I can send you a copy of a workbook with it already built in.

```
Option Explicit

' User Defined Function to Average totals for only orders that contain specific string
' Pass the range and string you are looking for to the function
' Note the criteria string is case senstive so "chicken" is not the same as "Chicken"
'
' Example: =Average_Orders_Subset(A1:C13,"Chicken")
'
Public Function Average_Orders_Subset(rng As Range, criteria As String) As Double
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim arrData()   As Variant
Dim arrOrder()  As Variant
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long
Dim cnt         As Long
Dim sum         As Double
Dim avg         As Double

    ' The worksheet with data
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Counter and array to keep track of order letters
    cnt = 0
    ReDim arrOrder(cnt)


    With ws

        ' Create an array with all the values
        arrData = rng.Value2

        ' Iterate through the array looking for orders with the criteria e.g., "Chicken"
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)

            ' If criteria is found
            If arrData(i, 2) = criteria Then

                If cnt > 0 Then

                    ' If the array of order letters is less than 0
                    If arrData(i, 1) <> arrOrder(cnt - 1) Then

                        ' Checking if the order letter is already in the array so orders with two Chicken
                        ' or multipe of any criteria don't get double counted
                        ' Add them to the order letter array
                        arrOrder(cnt) = arrData(i, 1)
                        cnt = cnt + 1
                        ReDim Preserve arrOrder(cnt)

                    End If

                ElseIf cnt = 0 Then

                    ' This is to add the first occurence of the critera to the order array
                    arrOrder(cnt) = arrData(i, 1)
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    ReDim Preserve arrOrder(cnt)

                End If

            End If

        Next i

        ' Remove the last empty value in the order array
        ' this is a result of the count expanding the array after the value is added
        ReDim Preserve arrOrder(UBound(arrOrder) - 1)

        ' Reset counter
        cnt = 0
        sum = 0

        ' For all the values in the order array
        For i = LBound(arrOrder) To UBound(arrOrder)

            ' For all the values in the range
            For j = 2 To UBound(arrData)

                ' If a row in the range matches the order letter add that value to the sum
                If arrData(j, 1) = arrOrder(i) Then
                    sum = sum + arrData(j, 3)
                    ' Keep track of the number of summed values for an average
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                End If

            Next j

        Next i

        ' Calculte the average
        avg = (sum / cnt)
        ' Pass the average back to the formula
        Average_Orders_Subset = avg

    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```